# Changing fragment view has no effect

Tags: java, android

Im changing the view of a fragment with the following code

```
public void updateView() {
    View newView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_lobby, (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(mContainerId),
            false);

    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(mContainerId);
    container.removeAllViews();

    container.addView(newView);
}
```

Until the addView everything is fine, but then the new view aint added, the fragment remains empty.

If i change my code to display R.layout.fragment_lobby first and in updateView i change it to what is currently the first content then i see the R.layout.fragment_lobby correct and it voids the container again in updateView.

In all the other postings ive found about updating or modifying the view object of fragments that was the suggested code but it does not work for me. If you need some of the xml just tell me, they are both LinearLayout's and the content is (for testing) nearly the same, just different controls, nothing fancy.

Comment: Where is this code? In one of your fragment classes?

Comment: currently yes. But it doesnt matter where i put it, its always blank. I find absolutely no possibility to display anything else but the very first tab that was created by default. I cant even add a second tab to the with a FragmentTransaction, its ignored.

Comment: Try replacing `ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(mContainerId);` with `ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)getView().findViewById(mContainerId);`

Comment: I tried those and some other stuff (ill add it in the posting), always the same result: Blank screen. I thought maybe there is something wrong with my LobbyFragment class but adding it by default in the FragmentPagerAdapter it shows up perfectly.